# Remove old alarm and set a new one with Alarm manager

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

I am having a issue with alarm manager. I need to remove old alarm set to a particular time and reset the alarm to new time. I have tried many scenarios and none working for me. Any help should be greately appreciated.`enter code here`

// To remove alarm

```
    am = (AlarmManager)  getContext().getSystemService( ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent( getContext(),AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( getContext(), profileFragmentRequestCode, i, 0);
    am.cancel(p);
    p.cancel();
```

// To set new alarm

```
    am = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

       /* Retrieve a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast */
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), profileFragmentRequestCode, alarmIntent,  0);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 55);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    } else {
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

Comment: @snachmsm Yes it is an UNIQUE NUMBER I AM USING

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have used same `REQUEST_CODE` with your `PendingIntent` both for `setting` and `canceling` alarm.

**SET ALARM:**

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), REQUEST_CODE, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent)
```

**CANCEL ALARM:**

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), REQUEST_CODE, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Yes I used the same request code for both. I found out the solution   

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 55);

Above line of code is making the problem.. Thanks for the solution provided.